# cloud based hosted database solution for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, hosting, web-hosting

What kind of cloud based hosted database solution(s) are available for hosting mongodb as a service.

MongoHQ seems to offer this service, but are there other vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoDB hosting data is here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hosting+Center).

Mongo HQ and Mongo Machine are the only spots really offering to "host" it per se. It looks like Heroku works with MongoHQ, so you can already get a flexible hosted solution.

The rest of the list include are VPS or cloud providers (*i.e.: install on your own machine*).

There are a few good reasons for this, but the primary reason is simply that MongoDB is still very new.

So if you want to build a "hobby" app, you'll have to use MongoHQ pulling data over the net. Otherwise you can host your own on your server. Unfortunately, there's not a lot of in-between right now.

Comment: I tried pulling data from MongoHQ over the net and it was very slow. Unfortunately you need to use a 64 bit OS for larger data sets and in dev environment you usually don't find such machines, which happens to be my current problem.

Comment: If you need a 64-bit machine and don't have one handy, then it's time to spend some money. I mean, if you have large data sets AND you're worried about speed, then you pretty much have to spend money for any solution. If you're trying to "submarine" the solution, then you'll have to find a box somewhere or look to EC2/Joyent/Rackspace/etc.